# How to make code align after pasting in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webstorm

I was wondering if someone can help me figure out how to make my code align after I copy and paste some code in WebStorm?

For example, when I copy a block of code and paste it below, the new block of code gets shifted to the right even though my cursor is all the way to the left. I can easily highlight the code and do a SHIFT + TAB but its kind of tedious to do it all the time. Thanks.

[image: Pasted Code being shifted right]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferences > Editor > General > Enter > Smart Indent

And look at the image you can see reformat on paste

[image]